# Download data for StackOverflow User Survey?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, community, stack-overflow-developer-survey

The [DropBox link to download the data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tiautbb955sa9ql/2013%20Stack%20Overflow%20Survey%20Responses.xlsx) for this survey is expired.  Is there another place to get the data?

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/02/2013-stack-overflow-user-survey-results/

Comment: For those without Google account, I uploaded to external host: http://www.filedropper.com/2013stackoverflowsurveysummary (dunno for how long it will survive though)

Comment: I was able to find a link which does not require logging in to Google Drive:
https://2ff8e5f7e395123d21ed142d1e4ada08c1829e0c.googledrive.com/host/0BwIexitMAu8ceG95UUkyUGlRM0U/ Enjoy! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about that. I actually noticed on Friday, but couldn't work out what to point the link to. This morning I got the word from Alison to change the link to:

https://drive.google.com/a/stackoverflow.com/#folders/0BwIexitMAu8ceG95UUkyUGlRM0U

It includes *all* of our survey results, not just the most recent.

Enjoy!

Comment: "Unable to access folder with ID: 0ADRrPhHMLcQCUk9PVA. Check access permissions on the folder."

Comment: Plus, this force one to have Google account, which is a major downside

Comment: @Sha - try again. Should be public.

Comment: @Oded nice, working fine now. Google caching this time? ;)

Comment: Naw, wrong access rights.

Comment: @Oded (or Jon :)) you can also update [2012 Survery results](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/01/2012-stack-overflow-user-survey-results/) and [2011 Survey results](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/survey-results/) adding the link, for those who stumble on them before/without seeing 2013 results first. :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Done.

Comment: Thanks @Jon, one last thing [this link](https://2ff8e5f7e395123d21ed142d1e4ada08c1829e0c.googledrive.com/host/0BwIexitMAu8ceG95UUkyUGlRM0U/) appears to list all the files without requiring one to log into the Drive. Not sure if it's a permanent link, but if it is, guess better use it.